# SFTP Issues in Micro Integrator 1.1.0 with WSO2EI 7 Integration Studio

Tags: sftp, wso2-enterprise-integrator, vfs, wso2-micro-integrator

I am New to and using WSO2EI Integration Studio 7.0.0 I am getting an error while moving files from my local to SFTP but files are moving to SFTP in this scenario i have used send mediator. Also i am unable to move sftp to local it showing fully error only. 
1. VFS Parameters File URI not working
2. VFS Parameter Move after process not working

I have used Micro Integrator 1.1.0

Please help me to fix the issues.

Comment: You should provide some more information, eg. logs. Now it's impossible to determine if the problem is in the application or in network or in SFTP-servers

Comment: Please attach the carbon.log files to pin point the root cause for this issue.